# Insert DateTime format in combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I've Harvest_Base class where all DateTime formats are shown;

```
class Harvest_Base
{

    public static DateTime storeTime(String date)
    {

        DateTime returnValue = new DateTime();

        if (date == "")
            return returnValue;

            //Time or Date Component Does not Exist
            string[] formats= {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", 
               "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", 
               "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", 
               "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm", 
               "h:mm tt","hh:mm tt","HH:mm:ss","H:mm","HH:mm","h:mmtt"};
            DateTime result;

            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
                returnValue = result;
            else
                returnValue = DateTime.Today;

        return returnValue;

    }

}
```

I have view class in which I've two comboboxes for starttime and stoptime. I want to do something bu which these comboBoxes should show me values in "hh:mm tt" format.

My questions are:

1. Is binding required here? If yes, please explain with code in answer.
2. If binding not required then what can I do to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

Either you bind the combo box directly to the `DateTime` and apply a `StringFormat` on the binding, or you bind to a string representing your `DateTime` in the proper format. You could also use a value converter, but it's a bit overkill.

Here's the [`StringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) in the `Binding` clause

```
{Binding Path=PathToTheDateTime, StringFormat={}{0:MM-dd-yyyy}}
```

Change the `MM-dd-yyyy` part to your liking.